# How to integrate the Spring Framework with Crystal report

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, crystal-reports, spring-mvc

here is my problem I have spring framework and I want to integrate Crystal report

the problem is when Report call the servlet CrystalReportViewerServlet, the spring dispacher don't find it so how I can make spring dispacher to call a default servlet that is declare on my Web.xml

here is my web.xml

```
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-
class>com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CrystalReportViewerHandler</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <context-param>
    <param-name>crystal_image_uri</param-name>
    <param-value>/gaa.vargas.furniture/crystalreportviewers</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>crystal_image_use_relative</param-name>
    <param-value>webapp</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: You can retrieve the Spring beans to your CrystalReportViewerServlet instead of calling this servlet from your Spring dispatcher. I had a similar case where my custom servlet is not found by my Spring dispatcher. What I did is call the Spring beans within my custom servlet.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish that requires access to the Spring context from within the CrystalReportViewerServlet?  There may be another way to achieve the necessary end.